# Cannot resolve symbol Apache in Intellij

Tags: java, apache, maven

I have been through the other answers but none of them seemed to help me. I am just starting out with programming.

```
import jdk.incubator.http.HttpClient;
import jdk.incubator.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.*;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;


public class app {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qdjna4Nh7DM");
        HttpResponse res = client.execute(get);

        String strng = EntityUtils.toString(res.getEntity());
        System.out.println(strng);
        String str1 = "playability";
        if(strng.toLowerCase().contains(str1.toLowerCase())){
            System.out.println("waah");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("naah");
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the data out of a site and see if it contains the world playability in it.

The problem I am having is that intellij cannot resolve symbol apache here.

I have built a maven project with the following pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>driverscrape</groupId>
    <artifactId>driverscrape</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Am I missing something? Is there something else that I should do? Please guide me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your `pom.xml`, right between `</build>` and `</project>`

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
          <version>4.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Explanation: You are missing the library. You need to tell your project which library you need, how it is called and which version you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the apache http package as a dependency in your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Note:please check the exact package name